# Extension for Modern-Fortran in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, fortran

I am trying to use Visual Studio (VS) Code to debug and run Fortran. I have already installed the extensions for 'Modern Fortran', 'Fortran Breakpoint Support' and 'fortran'.

I also added the following two files. One is launch.json. The content is written below.

```
"version": "0.0.1",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Fortran Launch (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "x86",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:/Application_Softwares/MinGW-W64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "gfortran"
        },
        {
            "name": "Intel Debug Attach",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ] }\
```

The other file is tasks.json and the content is written below.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "gfortran",
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceRoot}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
    ]
}
```

Then I wrote a test file and the content is written below.

```
PROGRAM HELLO
IMPLICIT NONE

OPEN (UNIT=3, FILE='hello.dat', STATUS='UNKNOWN')
WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) 'Hello World!'
CLOSE (UNIT=3)

STOP
END PROGRAM HELLO
```

When I clicked the 'Start Debugging' button in the 'Run' manual, VS code shows the following error message.

```
You don't have an extension for debugging 'Fortran-Modern'. Should we find a 'Fortran-Modern' extension in the Marketplace?
```

I have already installed this extension. I do not know why it shows this error message.

Would anyone please tell me how to sort out this problem?

Thank you in advance.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have any error messages please **always**, really always, include them in your question **as text**, not just as pictures. It is really very important. People with a similar problem must be able to search and find your question amd the answers. See [ask].

Comment: @Vladimir Ok, I have already revised my question. Would you please have a look at it and give me some suggestions on the solution? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you have "Modern Fortran" installed. The error code however speaks about "Fortran - Modern". This is not necessarily the same thing. What happens when you press "Find Fortran - Modern extension"?

Comment: @Vladimir The VS code does not show any other Fortran related extension. This is why I do not know the reason. I guess I did not set the path for the extension correctly but I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: That is possible. Unfortunately, therevareclearly not that many people here who use Fortran in VS Code.

Comment: what is "Fortran-Morden"

Comment: @starball Just a typo, or rather grammatical error because the OP made it repeatedly. But it does not seem to be present in the configuration shown.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 2 different language extensions for Fortran in VS Code. You only need to use [Modern Fortran](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortran-lang.linter-gfortran) (and *please* use the Pre-Release).
The features you are looking for are natively supported in Modern Fortran so there is no need for additional extensions.

---

Full disclosure: I am the author of Modern Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Fortran with VS Code for over 3 years.
'Fortran Breakpoint Support' is not working good with Modern Fortran. Modern Fortran ready support breakpoint recently. As @gnikit said, you only need to use Pre-release Modern Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

The following set of extensions works for me:
Fortran
Modern Fortran
Code Runner

- with the compiler: tdm64-gcc